# When do activity's instance variables get initialized?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my android application I have a strange bug. An instance variable like below gets assigned to it's default value unexpectedly at run time (in this case - false). When do this type of variables get initialized in android activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean isInitialized = false;  // <- When do this variable get initialized?
}
```

Comment: when you call this activity at that time it will be initialize.

Comment: Runtime as in? When exactly?

Comment: What do you mean in "call this activity"? Do you mean activity's onCreate?

Comment: when onCreate is called

Comment: Is there any official documentation about that?

Comment: The documentation is part of the Java Language Specification. Instance members are initialized when the instance is created, before the constructor method is invoked. **not when onCreate() is called, but before**.  See the [Java Language Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for an introduction to initializing fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance variables in Java are initialized when the instance is created.

Most of the time objects would get instantiated with `new`.

In case of activities, they are instantiated by the Android framework using reflection (see [`Instrumentation#newActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#newActivity(java.lang.Class%3C?%3E,%20android.content.Context,%20android.os.IBinder,%20android.app.Application,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.content.pm.ActivityInfo,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))). Then initialization for `Context` is performed and activity `onCreate()` gets called on the instance.

For details, have a look at [`ActivityThread` source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2293).

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have "global variables".

You are talking about `instance variables`. They are initialized each time a new instance is created.

Comment: Yes, I understand but what about activities. They never get initialized using constructor. I want to know if there is any specific activity lifecycle method when they get initialized. I am talking about the variables that are assigned outside of a method.

Comment: you can debug your code to understand the lifecycle activities, in the other side this link may help you:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: "assigned outside of a method"? you mean "declared outside of a method", instance variables.

Comment: Yes I mean declared outside of a method.

Comment: "if there is any specific activity lifecycle method when they get initialized" - No, there isn't. Even in pure Java there is no such thing. The first piece of Java code called upon instance creation is the constructur. And by that time, all instance variables are already initialized by the JVM.